# How to completely uninstall/remove Marklogic 9 on centos7

Tags: marklogic

I tried to remove and reinstall MarkLogic 9 on Centos7 (sandbox) following steps.

login as su

1)service MarkLogic stop

2)yum remove MarkLogic

3)shutdown -r now

4)yum install MarkLogic-9.0-RHEL7-8.0-9.1.x86_64.rpm

5)service MarkLogic start

I opened browser port 8001 ML9 admin GUI for first time it displayed login screen user/password. Look like ML9 orphans still remain in system.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset a MarkLogic installation, you do not usually need to uninstall MarkLogic. MarkLogic creates a directory to store configurations and data for the running instance. On Linux systems the default is /var/opt/MarkLogic.

To reset the installation:

1. Shutdown MarkLogic: `systemctl stop MarkLogic`
2. Remove the MarkLogic instance data: `rm -rf /var/opt/MarkLogic`
3. Start MarkLogic: `systemctl start MarkLogic`

Now when you access port 8001, it will prompt you to initialize a new MarkLogic instance, and setup the databases.